# Mysterious 1 when using php include

Tags: php

My backup content (should the database fail) is brought in with include(). For some reason, there's a mysterious lone '1' below the div the include is wrapped in. It does it every time, but just on the content include. I've checked the function, all pages involved, no stray 1. If it loads from the database, everything's fine.

Any ideas why?

```
(empty($Content)?(empty($dbContent)?include($URL):$dbContent):$Content);
```

That's the core of the function. No code to provide really, just a strange 1.

Comment: Dare to show some code?

Comment: how about binary search? remove code till `1` goes away.. now check what you have removed..

Comment: Oh god! nesting ternaries

Comment: @MarkBaker What is so bad about nesting ternaries? I keep seeing this but I couldn't find a reason why it's bad on google.

Comment: They're nested to make the code more readable. There are about 7 functions that use a very similar line. I see no reason not to - it was condensed from the working file. Even with the old file with lengthy code the 1 is still there. Just on this include. Any real help or just more down votes for a real question.

Comment: This doesn't make the line more readable to non-native Klingon speakers, but the reverse... especially with the complete lack of spacing or multi-lines and indentation. Nested ternaries aren't recommended because the logic isn't intuitive (the number of problem posts with nested ternaries here on SO bears that out)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was the nested ternaries causing the issue. It outputs a 1 right after the function, as if it were saying echo include()

Very odd, because the rest of the functions seem to be working fine. The only difference is the include().

I'll switch back to longhand if any more odd behavior appears. It would be nice to know why it was treating it like it had echo in front of it.